# clang undefined reference to `__fprintf_chk'

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

I am trying to link to my project some static libraries compiled with gcc-5.
In my project i use clang to build. I have following errors:

```
undefined reference to 'stderr'
undefined reference to '__fprintf_chk'
undefined reference to '__vfprintf_chk'
```

Comment: You can't really mix object files created by different compilers. And a static library is nothing more than an archive of object files.

Comment: At all ? I have error related with stack protector and setting -fno-stack-protector helped. Are there some tricks like that to fix that ?

Comment: Well, it *might* be possible if you link with the GCC runtime (e.g. `-lgcc` or similar). I would personally still try to avoid the mixing anyway.